# How do i save video to new directory in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, avkit

I'm working with filemanager. So far I'm able to initialize my directory but when I try to save data there, the error i get is "error: Cannot create file".There seems to be an issue with the way I'm creating my path because when I use a temporary url, I am able to save to the photos library.

Here's the working temporary url code

```
var tempURL: URL? {
let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
if directory != "" {
  let path = directory.appendingPathComponent("video.mov")
  return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
}
return nil
```

}

Here's the code where I execute the recording

---

```
  do {
      let videoPath = "SavedVideos"
      var videoDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
      videoDirectory = videoDirectory.appending(path: videoPath)
      videoDirectory = videoDirectory.appending(path: "000001")
      videoDirectory = videoDirectory.appending(path: "video.mov")
      movieOutput.startRecording(to: videoDirectory, recordingDelegate: self)
  }
  catch {
      print("error recording to video directory: \(error)")
  }
```

---

Again, changing **startRecording(to:videoDirectory** to **startRecording(to: tempURL!** , I able to record. Any insights on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add directories to the path (`SavedVideos` and `000001`) without creating them , so Insert `createDirectory` like below

```
do {
    var videoDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    videoDirectory = videoDirectory.appending(path: "SavedVideos/000001")
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: videoDirectory.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    videoDirectory = videoDirectory.appending(path: "video.mov")
    movieOutput.startRecording(to: videoDirectory, recordingDelegate: self)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction. I'm no longer getting the error. However, when the recording stops, my didFinishrecordingTo method never triggers so the file isnt being saved for some reason. It does trigger with the temporary url.

Comment: Can you print error inside `didFinishRecordingTo:from:error` ?

Comment: I realize what I did wrong. Thanks for your help @Sh_kan